# Is the dual of a conic program $\min_{x\in K} c^T x$ subject to $Ax=b$ also a conic program?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, dual-cone

Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix (over $\mathbb{R}$), $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$, $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n $ is a closed, convex, pointed cone with non-empty interior. We define a conic program to be $$ \min_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n} c^Tx \\ \text{subject to } Ax = b , x\in K$$

Furthermore, define the dual problem to be $$ \max_{y\in \mathbb{R}^m, z \in \mathbb{R}^n} b^Ty \\ \text{subject to } c = z + A^Ty, z \in K^*$$ where $K^*$ is the dual cone of $K$.

**Question:** Is the dual problem also a conic program (by the definition given)? If I try the obvious solution where $(y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^m \times K^*$, then the issue is that $\mathbb{R}^m \times K^*$ is a closed convex cone with non-empty interior *but is not pointed*. How can I get around this?

Thank you.

**Edit:** To clarify, a cone is defined as a set $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying $x \in K \implies ax \in K$ for all $a \geq 0$. A cone is pointed if it satisfies $K \cap (-K) = \{0\}.$

Comment: Out of curiosity, what reference are you using that defines conic programs to be defined over _pointed_ cones?

Comment: This is from lectures in a course I'm following – unsure what reference the lecturer is following. They assume K is a proper cone when defining conic programs. Here proper cone is defined to be closed, convex, pointed cone with non-empty interior as stated in my question.

Comment: @DavidM. Is this definition of conic programs unusual?

Comment: I don’t do much conic programming, but I checked Wikipedia, and they don’t define it this way. If you don’t require $K$ to be pointed, your problem goes away.

Comment: Why do you think that $\mathbb R^m \times K^*$ isn't pointed?

Comment: @user251257 If you take any nonzero vector $u \in \mathbb{R}^m$ then $(\pm u, 0) \in \mathbb{R}^m \times K^*$.

Comment: pointed means that the cone contains $0$ ...

Comment: @user251257 That would imply that every cone is pointed, since every cone contains $0$ (by definition of a cone)

Comment: @DavidM. It depends actually on the definition of cone. just check the wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_cone

Comment: I think there are different definitions being used here. Wikipedia also seems to have slightly different definitions from those I'm using. For me, pointed means $K \cap (-K) = \{0\}$ and a cone is a set for which $x \in K \implies ax \in K$ for all $a \geq 0$.

Comment: To be pedantic the dual problem is not a conic program. But it is equivalent to a conic program by using the usual tricks ($\max b^T y = -\min -b^T y$, $y = u - v$ with $u,v \ge 0$).

Comment: @user251257 I am indeed trying to show that the dual problem is equivalent to a conic program (as defined in the question). Can you write that out please? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dual program is equivalent to a conic program, by applying following transformations

1. Replace $y\in\mathbb R^m$ with $y=u - v$ for $u,v\in\mathbb R^m_+$ (cone of non-negative orthant).
2. Replace $\max ...$ with $-\min -(...)$.

Finally, we obtain the following equivalent conic program,
that is we can map the feasible points of both programs into other (not necessarily bijectively) and we can map the optimal points of both programs into other:

$$ \min_{(u,v,z)} \; \begin{bmatrix}-b \\ b \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}^T \begin{bmatrix}u \\ v \\ z \end{bmatrix} $$
$$ \text{s.t. } \begin{bmatrix}A^T & -A^T & I\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}u \\ v \\ z \end{bmatrix} = c, \; \begin{bmatrix}u \\ v \\ z \end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb R^m_+ \times \mathbb R^m_+ \times K^*$$

*Notes:*

- If $y$ is given, then we can take $u = \max(y, 0)$ and $v = \max(-y, 0)$ component-wise.
- We can think of $u$ as the "positive" part of $y$ and $v$ as the "negative" part of $y$.

Comment: Nice trick. This is indeed a conic program by my definition I think. Thank you!